# how to get record for which given date falls between set of dates of same column in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a table which is having tour details ie. empcode, tourId, tour place and tour date I want to check who is on tour on a given date ?

Employee X is on tour from 01-01-2016 to 10-01-2016
Employee Y is on tour from 07-01-2016 to 12-01-2016
Employee X is on tour from 12-01-2016 to 15-01-2016

Table is having following details

```
EmpCode TourId PlaceFrom PlaceTo TourDate
100       1       delhi   jaipur  01-01-2016
100       1       jaipur  mumbai  05-01-2016
100       1       mumbai  delhi   10-01-2016
101       2       delhi   pune    07-01-2016
101       2       pune    delhi   12-01-2016
100       3       alwar   jaipur  12-01-2016
100       3       jaipur  udaipur 13-01-2016
100       3       udaipur alwar   15-01-2016
```

TourId denotes a unique tour
If I search who is on tour on 01-01-2016 it should return 100
If I search who is on tour on 08-01-2016 it should return 100 and 101
If I search who is on tour on 12-01-2016 it should return 102
If I search who is on tour on 14-01-2016 it should return 100

how to get the desired output in single query in postgresql.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation functions:

```
select EmpCode, TourId
from t
group by EmpCode, TourId
having '2016-01-01' between min(TourDate) and max(TourDate);
```

`TourId` is optional in the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmpCode
FROM TourDetails
GROUP BY EmpCode
HAVING '2016-01-14' BETWEEN MIN(TourDate) AND MAX(TourDate);
```

The EmpCode most likely should not be present in that table but in the upper-level Tours table.
Also, please consider using ISO 8601 for dates, or a TIMESTAMP field.